# How do I compare higher order types?

Tags: c++

I want to have something like this:

```
std::cout << std::is_same<Buffer<int>, Buffer<float>>::value;
```

But instead of comparing the whole type I just want to know if the type is a buffer.

```
std::cout << std::is_buffer<Buffer<int>>::value // true;
std::cout << std::is_buffer<Buffer<float>>::value // true;
```

Would this be possible? Maybe with the help of templates of templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a simple trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_buffer : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_buffer<Buffer<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

This doesn't take into account cv-qualifiers though.

If you want to take into account cv-qualifiers, you would just need to specialise it a little more:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_buffer<const T> : is_buffer<T> {};

template<typename T>
struct is_buffer<volatile T> : is_buffer<T> {};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a trait class like the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> struct is_buffer : std::false_type {};

template<class T> struct is_buffer<Buffer<T> > : std::true_type {};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
class is_buffer : public std::false_type
{ };

template<typename T>
class is_buffer<Buffer<T>> : public std::true_type
{ };
```

So the `is_buffer` which inherits `std::true_type` will be used if the template argument is of type `Buffer<T>`, otherwise the `std::false_type` one will be used.

Comment: Traits have historically always been `struct` due to the fact that the default inheritance scheme is `public`. It's a bit weird to see a `class` trait despite nothing being wrong with it.